# Are there standard (topic) dictionaries for MQTT-capable devices/sensors?

Tags: mqtt

We are thinking of using MQTT and I was wondering if there was a standard for topic dictionaries a sensors/devices - kind of like a MIB file for SNMP?

Are these topic dictionaries published to a central repository?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might get more precise answers if you can add a bit more about what you're trying to do. What kind of sensors for example you are using to get what kind of data? You can also check out the site [tour].

Comment: This question wasn't for a particular sensor, but was a general question. When we implement sensors/devices at my work, we make an SNMP OID dictionary in the form of a MIB file - I was wondering if there was an analogous system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: NO

The only standard topic structure is the `$SYS/` prefix that shows internal state of the broker and then the content differs between brokers.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with hardillb's answer. There is no central repository. To add:

MQTT is just the transport on top of which you can layer any other protocol. This is very immature, we only know of a couple of somewhat standard protocols:

1. Sparkplug https://s3.amazonaws.com/cirrus-link-com/Sparkplug+Topic+Namespace+and+State+ManagementV2.1+Apendix++Payload+B+format.pdf
   being de-facto standardized by Eclipse https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-tahu
2. LWM2M-MQTT https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e1/LWM2M_MQTT_EclipseIoTDaysGrenoble.pdf
3. Each of the cloud IoT platforms (AWS, Azure, etc) has their own topic namespace and protocol.
4. many ad-hoc implementations. Just subscribe to # on any of the public MQTT brokers (iot.eclipse.org, broker.hivemq.com, etc).